# var_dump not returning a value

Tags: php, mysql

I want to allow a user the upload an image (file) for their profile picture, on my website. They upload the image via an HTML form, but I am having trouble moving the file to the folder I want it to. I don't want to mess with the php.ini file to change the upload path. I want to use move_uploaded_file(). I try and use $tmp= $_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'] and var_dump($tmp), but It keeps returning a value of (0). So, I think the problem has something to do with that. Here is my code,

Here is my HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload_img.php">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="32768"/>
<input type="text" name="name" value=""/>
<input type="file" name="picture" value="picture"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload"/>
</form>
```

And my PHP:

```
<?php

define('GW_UPLOADPATH', 'images/');

$picture= $_FILES['picture']['name'];
$name= $_POST['name'];
$tmp= $_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'];

var_dump($picture);
var_dump($name);
var_dump($tmp);

$connect= mysqli_connect(//connect params)
or die('error connecting with the database');

$query= "INSERT INTO pics (pic, name) VALUES ('$picture', '$name')";

$target= GW_UPLOADPATH . $picture ;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $target);))
{

mysqli_query($connect, $query)
or die('error with query');
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried dumping `$_FILES['picture']` yet?

Comment: i get  array(5) { ["name"]=> string(9) "aaron.jpg" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" ["error"]=> int(2) ["size"]=> int(0)

Comment: *sigh* http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: I already know the errors. What I don't get, is why am I getting it? I changed the MAX_FILE_SIZE to 100kb and the image is only 93kb and I still get an error.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue likely has something to do with php's upload_max_filesize and post_max_size. Check those 2 settings in your php.ini and make sure the file you are trying to upload isn't larger than either of them.